# Is meta questions in the Twitter feed a design feature or a bug?

Tags: discussion

I have (belatedly) accessed the Twitter feed and was surprised to see that in the last 24 hours there has a preponderance of meta questions highlighted. Given that linking there will expose our "family room voices" rather than our "front room manners" (to use an old expression), is this how the system is meant to operate?

If it is, are others aware that our "more robust" comments on meta are being advertised in this way?

Comment: I didn't even know there was a Twitter feed. What is the Twitter name?

Comment: Look at https://twitter.com/StackGenealogy

Answer (score 3):

This is a deliberate design feature. [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) on Meta sites are included in the pool of potential candidates for which to identify "interesting" posts. This is done both to help promote the presence of the meta site and also to let people know "Hey, here's something interesting that's brewing in this community from a governance standpoint".

We do not include items with [support](/questions/tagged/support) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) since those are less of the "interesting" stuff and more just the knitty-gritty of fixing up the site and making everything work for both the community and the mechanisms.

Comment: In this context, I presume that "we" means Community Management?

Comment: Am I the only person puzzled by the fact that a meta question (1186) posed on 19 Oct and not active since 23 Oct was deemed to be sufficiently "interesting" to be tweeted on 30 Oct? Or that the fact we do NOT HAVE a newsletter (1196) was breaking news on 29 Oct?

Comment: "We" in this context means Stack Exchange Inc. In that, since it was our dev team that wrote the algorithm, it was our choice to not include those items. As for the selection method, it's not the most robust or intelligent of algorithms, at times. It just needs posts that hit certain criteria thresholds (to which I do not know the numbers off the top of my head).

Answer (score 1):

I had missed this question, so until recently I was unaware that questions from Meta were going out on Twitter.

A suggestion:  rather than excluding [support](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) and [bug](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug), can we consider this from the other direction, of what questions might be of most interest to people who don't know about Stack Exchange already?

If we Tweeted the Meta questions tagged [featured](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) it would allow us to send out the Qs about the Weekly Topic Challenge and the Weekly Chats, but not the everyday Qs about the internal workings of the site, which have less interest to the non-SE audience.

Another option might be to create a tag for Meta called [tag: tweet-me] which would indicate that the Meta question is Tweet-worthy.  This might allow the sites to control their own Twitter content with less processing load on the system; surely it is easier to check for the presence of a tag than it would be to calculate a question's worthiness by some other algorithm.

The reason I ask this is that new users who look at @StackGenealogy in order to consider whether they should follow it may not be familiar with Stack Exchange's way of doing things. If they see a list of questions about our content, they may be tempted to come and answer some of the questions.

Once they are here, we can indroduce them to the joys of Meta, but I don't think Meta discussions are particularly useful as an advertising mechanism.

I have posted an answer on the Meta question mentioned by @PolyGeo in the contents: [Should site-specific Twitter feeds be tweeting meta questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247576/261421)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118055/should-site-specific-twitter-feeds-be-tweeting-meta-questions seems to agree with you and @Fortiter - [meta-tag:tweet-me] sounds like it could be useful - perhaps restricted to [trusted users](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) and moderators.